# Imported DXF has no position attribute using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, import, geolocation, dxf

I am using QGIS 3.10.8 and still getting my head around QGIS.

I'm trying to import some route data from dxf into my QGIS project. when I import and set the CRS correctly it is in the correct place, but the attribute table has no position information.

I have tried saving as DXF 2013 as well as 2018. I have imported using the *project - import/export - import layers from DWG/dxf* I have dragged and dropped onto the workspace, I have created a new vector layer and loaded the DXF.

Is there a fundamental step I am missing?

Will I have to digitise the line?

If there is no position information in the attribute table, how is it getting positioned in the correct place?

[image]

Comment: At its simplest, a vector dataset (also known as a feature class) has features, each feature has a geometry (the coordinates) and attributes.  The geometry/coordinates don't have to be in the attribute table, the GIS software knows how to link the coordinates to the attributes.  It's an implementation detail you don't need to worry about, unless you have a specific reason to want to see them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: I managed to find all the information I required using the geometry tools. A combination of find vertices and add geometry attributes gave me everything I was looking for. 
Thanks for taking the time to reply